# mouse over on text to change text with scrolling animation with css

Tags: html, css

i want to change this "EMAIL" text to change on mouseover to the specific email (like "JOHN.SNOW@GMAIL.COM) with an horizontal scrolling animation. this is the HTML

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="contact" href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
  <a class="contact" href="#">EMAIL</a>
  <a class="contact" href="#">CREDITS</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OKay, Run the following code snippet, I Use an overlay to make the effect like scroll

Try this, may help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="">Email</div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">JOHN.SNOW@GMAIL.COM</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but if i wanted to make that animation horizontal? and it would be cool if the email text could "disappear" befor the animation

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.contact:hover {
    font-size: 0;
}
.contact:hover::after {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a class="contact" href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
            <a class="contact" href="#" data-hover="john.snow@gmail.com">EMAIL</a>
            <a class="contact" href="#">CREDITS</a>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this seems to do a strange a trange glitchy animation, i'm trying to fix it

Comment: I think I might've fixed it... here's a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Le70akum/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated snippet on how you can achive it.

Firstly,

You need to hide excess characters you can do that by providing a fixed width to the `.contact` container and making `overflow:hidden;`

In the below snippet change the width  `max-width: 200px;` to control the number of characters of email to be shown.

Secondly,

Use `transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;` to control animation of the scroll while using `transform` on hover to provide scroll position using `transform: translateX(-200px);`

Here, is the working example

```css
a.contact {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a.contact>span::after {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
  transform-origin: right;
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-text);
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

a.contact>span:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  transition-duration:4s;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="contact" href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
  <a class="contact" href="#"><span data-text="EMAIL" data-hover="LONGGGGGGGGGGGGGGEMAIL@mail.com"></span></a>
  <a class="contact" href="#">CREDITS</a>
</div>
```

Comment: longgggmail is scrolling but i want to switch "EMAIL" with the real email with a fast-scrolling animation

Comment: that can be achieved as shown below using data-hover

Comment: @Syertim I have updated the above snippet, check out if it solves the problem.